# How can I fix my weekdays, to output specific info on Saturdays and Sundays. From Mon to Fri, the people are at work and Sat to Sun is the weekend

Tags: python, if-statement, count, simulation

This is part of a simulation. My current day acts as the current epoch and it always starts from 0. My current code is as follows:

```
    is_weekend = current_day % 5 == 0 or current_day % 6 == 0

    if is_weekend:
        print("people are at home")
    else:
        print("people are at work")

    for person in people:
        if is_weekend:
            person.location = "Home"
        else:
            person.location = "Work"
```

However, when I reach the second week of work in my programme, on Saturday they are at home but Sunday they are back at work. I thought using % would work but there seems to be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that we have `7 days` and you check for `multiples of 5 and 6`. With that logic, the `10th day` would be the same weekday as the `5th day` but that is wrong - a week later is the `12th day`. Also, `0 % x returns 0` so you have to take this into consideration when working with the modulo operator. In our case, it does not matter because we don't check for `0` anymore.

```
weekdays = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
for i in range(0, 14):
    day_of_week = i % 7;
    is_weekend = day_of_week == 5 or day_of_week == 6;
    print('The', i, 'day is a', weekdays[day_of_week], '=> is weekend?', is_weekend)
```

You have to check for a remainder of `5` and `6` for the current week because the week has 7 days.

```
The 0 day is a Mon => is weekend? False
The 1 day is a Tue => is weekend? False
The 2 day is a Wed => is weekend? False
The 3 day is a Thu => is weekend? False
The 4 day is a Fri => is weekend? False
The 5 day is a Sat => is weekend? True
The 6 day is a Sun => is weekend? True
The 7 day is a Mon => is weekend? False
The 8 day is a Tue => is weekend? False
The 9 day is a Wed => is weekend? False
The 10 day is a Thu => is weekend? False
The 11 day is a Fri => is weekend? False
The 12 day is a Sat => is weekend? True
The 13 day is a Sun => is weekend? True
```

This is how modulo works (in this case):

```
0 % 7 => 0 / 7 => remainder is 0
1 % 7 => 1 / 7 => remainder is 1
2 % 7 => 2 / 7 => remainder is 2
...
7 % 7 => 7 / 7 => remainder is 0
8 % 7 => 8 / 7 => remainder is 1
9 % 7 => 9 / 7 => remainder is 2
```

The modulo operator (in this case) will tell us how much is left when we divide the first number through 7 again and again ... until we reach a number that is smaller than the right number (i.e. 7) and this will be the result from the modulo operator.

```
300 / 7 = 42.8571 ... 42.8571 / 7 = 6.1224
```

but

```
300 % 7 = 6 <=> (int) (300 / 7) = 6
```

How close can we get without getting floating point numbers?
It is `294` because `42 * 7 = 294`, `6 is missing to 300` and `6 is smaller than 7, therefore, remainder 6`

Comment: Thank you for your help. This helped a lot and it outputs correctly now.